# Nifi gets crashed when injecting the data

Tags: apache-nifi

I use `ListenHTTP` as an input point for the Nifi process.

I send the data from CSV file that totally takes around 100Mb:

```
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

url = 'http://localhost:8085/contentListener'

df = pd.read_csv('demo_dataset.csv')

for i in df.index:
    data = df.iloc[i].to_json()
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The problem is that Nifi gets crashed after processing around 3000 entries. Then I should restart it (before restarting I also manually empty the logs and flowfile_repository folders).

Is there any parameter in the Nifi processor `ListenHTTP` or Nifi itslef that would help solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little unclear -- Apache NiFi crashes after handling 3000 100Mb files, or 3000 lines from a single file? In the first case, I would imagine that is a storage/heap problem. Can you please provide a stacktrace from `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log`?

If you are able to use NiFi 1.2.0+, I would recommend using the [*record* processors](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) to do your operations, as the performance is much better and the flow is easier to design. You can send the 100Mb CSV file as a single operation (or use `GetFile`) and have various processors operate on each line in the file independently.

Comment: It happens after sending 3000 lines from a single file using `ListenHTTP`. Would you recommend to use `GetFile`? My objective is to pass 100Mb of data (around 1 million of rows) through Nifi processors.

Comment: Moreover, `ListenHTTP` is probably not the best option to inject 100Mb of data. The process takes a lot of time and I have http related issues (I should set timeout and use time.sleep). Could I use `ListFile`->`FetchFile`->??? in order to read my CSV file line by line and convert each line to JSON string (as I do in my Python code)?

Comment: Reading a file off the file system will definitely be better. The HTTP spec isn’t as good for large file transfer. Either `GetFile` or `ListFile`/`FetchFile` will give you much better performance, and then you can parse the lines of the file with ease.

Comment: I appreciate a lot if you could show a demo sequence of processors, especially for reading line by line. As I can see `FetchFile` just gets the content of the file, but how can I inject it line by line to subsequent Nifi processors, so that each line is a simple JSON string?

Comment: Use `SplitContent` to split on a byte sequence, or `SplitText` to split on common line endings. If your input is JSON, you can also use `SplitJSON` to parse a JSON array into individual flowfiles, each containing one record. Again, if possible, evaluate the *record* processors first, as they are far more performant and easy-to-use.